# Input will not affect what if statement is used

Tags: c++

There is more to this code, but this is the only part that will not work. No matter what I put in to the "Change" variable, it will only give me the first if statement's code. How can I fix this?

```
std::cout << "Do you want to change any of this information? ";
std::string answer;
std::string x = "yes";
std::cin >> answer;
if(answer == x){
    std::cout << "What would you like to change:\nname(1), password(2), email(3), country(4), or cancel(5)?\nType the number of which you want to change: ";
    std::cin >> Change;
    if(Change = 1){
        std::cout << "Please type your new first name: ";
        std::cin >> FirstName;
        std::cout << "Middle Initial: ";
        std::cin >> MiddleInitial;
        std::cout << "Last Name: ";
        std::cin >> LastName;
        std::cout << "Thank you for signing up for Rowan's Demo Company!";
    }
    if(Change = 2){
        std::cout << "Please type your new password: ";
        std::cin >> Password;
        std::cout << "Thank you for signing up for Rowan's Demo Company!";
    }
    if(Change = 3){
        std::cout << "Please type your new email: ";
        std::cin >> Email;
        std::cout << "Thank you for signing up for Rowan's Demo Company!";
    }
    if(Change = 4){
        std::cout << "Please type your new country: ";
        std::cin >> Country;
        std::cout << "Thank you for signing up for Rowan's Demo Company!";
    }
    if(Change = 5){
        std::cout << "Thank you for signing up for Rowan's Demo Company!";
    }
}else{
    std::cout << "Thank you for signing up for Rowan's Demo Company!";
    }
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Hint  - equals operator is ==   ,not =

Comment: You used `==` at first then switched to `=`. Why? Look up in your book what each one means.

Comment: Are you sure this doesn't run _all_ those `if` clauses? Not just the first one.

Comment: `if(Change = 1){`   assigns `Change` to have a value `1`.  The result tested by the `if` is `1`, which is non-zero (always true).   Same goes for all the other `if` statements after that.

Comment: on what grounds was this question down-voted 4 times? The fact that the user has a question, or because this user is asking a question he doesn't know the answer to?

Answer (score 2):

Ah classic mistake. You can't use `=` for comparison, you have to use `==` instead. A single `=` is for assignment, which always overwrites your input.

The moment the `if` statement `if (Change = 1)` is evaluated, `Change` gets the value 1 and the expression furthermore evaluates to `true` which will execute the body of the `if`.

Remember: `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison.

Comment: Oh ok. So I will only use = for things like "int x = 5", and == for comparing?

Comment: @Theroarx exactly

Comment: One way to reduce chances of getting caught is to do comparisons like `if (1 ==  Change)` (swap the order of operands).    If you make a mistake of using `=` instead of `==`, the compiler will diagnose it (since it is not possible to assign to a constant literal).    Obviously this doesn't work for comparing the values of two variables that can both be assigned.

Comment: Also pay attention to the compiler warnings. Many modern compilers will spot the =/== mix-up and warn you. If yours doesn't, consider increasing the compiler's verbosity.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **=** (assignment operator) instead of **==** (comparison operator) for conditional expression in **if** and also you should be using **if()..else if()..else**  in your 1st level nesting! (not compulsory but here it is necessary!) 
you can also remove the **block ( {.......})** in some of your if statements  as there is only one statement included in it (to simplify it)!
**Eg:**

Both will give out same result!

```
 if(a==1)
    cout<<" you entered 1";
       // or
if(a==1) {
   cout<<"you entered 1";
}
```